# jQuery + Greasemonkey, Click event doesn't trigger on correct element?

Tags: jquery, dom, greasemonkey

```
$(Constants.Selectors.Submit_Button).bind('click', function () {
    GM_log('Event run: id = ' + this.id + ' self = ' + this);
});
```

The above code appears to run when the click event is triggered by the document (or otherwise some other all-page encompassing element or set of elements.) The console output is this:
Script: Event run: id = undefined self = [object XPCNativeWrapper [object HTMLDocument]]

The selector is a simple string "#buttonID" where buttonID is significantly obfuscated  (I'm sure there are no name conflicts) and is part of an HTML form I have injected into the page. (Namely an input element with the attribute "type" set to "button").

Does anyone know why this might be? I'm clueless on this one.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of version of jQuery you are using? 
It's been a while since i played in GM, but i found code of mine and it was done with 1.3.2 and it's still working for me as long as click function is under document ready function.

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(function(){
  $jq('#buttonID').click(function(){
   runCode;
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing something like this:

```
var elmLink = document.getElementById('somelink');
elmLink.onclick = 'my_func(this)';
```

do something like this:

```
var elmLink = document.getElementById('somelink');
elmLink.addEventListener("click", my_func, true);
```

from [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2005/11/01/avoid-common-greasemonkey-pitfalls.html?page=3)